# Jquery to dynamically add fields when you select from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need help in finalizing the dynamic addition of fields. I have HTML drop-down list.

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">           
<select id="list1" name="mytext[]">
        <option value="First">First</option>
        <option value="Second">Second</option>
        <option value="Third">Third</option>
        <option value="addq">Add your question</option>
</select>
<div id="youq">
<!-- You Question field --> 
</div>
</div>
    <a class="add_field_button">+ Add new question</a>
```

And Jquery code

```
//---- Add field script ----//
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 3;
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");  
var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append('<div><select name="mytext[]"><option value="First">First</option><option value="Second">Second</option><option value="Third">Third</option><option value="addq">Add your question</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;})
});

//Add question fields
$('#list1').change(function(){
    if($("#list1").val() == 'addq'){            
    $('#youq').html("<input class='youquestion' placeholder='Input you     question'/>");
    }
 else {$('#youq').html("");};
});
```

All this is done in order to be able to choose a question from the list or add your own.
Adding a drop-down lists by clicking the "+ Add new question" works well.
But I have problems with the addition of a text box when you select "Add your question" from the list.
If you select it from the first list, the field is displayed.
But if you click on "+ Add new question" and select "Add your question" in the new list is a new text field does not show.
Please help me.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqoon/zpgvLk05/2/)

Edit

Comment: 1> First of all when you click on **+ Add new question**, you are not adding any id to select tag.

2> And even if you add id it should be unique, else it will always take the first select with id **list1**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use .live() :

```
$("select").live('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'addq'){ 
        $(this).next().append("<input class='youquestion' placeholder='Input you question'/>");
    }
 });
```

You can check following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zpgvLk05/6/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem here is that the event listener for the "change" event is bound only to the dropdown with "#list1" id and it is bound via .change() method, which binds listeners only for existing DOM elements.

So, what you should do is change the "#list1" selector so that it selects both current and new dropdowns, for example, add a class, and change method that binds the listener to .on() or .live() or .delegate() (depending on your jQuery version), you can check documentation of this methods on the jQuery API page, .on() and .delegate() are used a bit differently, or if you don't want to check it, just change .change() to .live().

Answer (score 0):

I had updated your fiddle code. Now it is working fine. **[View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/zpgvLk05/9/)**

```
//Add question fields
$('#list1').live('change', function(){

        if($("#list1").val() == 'addq'){

            $('#youq').html("<input class='youquestion' placeholder='Input you question'/>");
        }
     else {
     $('#youq').html("");};
    });
```